# How can I implement a live broadcast like Instagram live using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, flutter-plugin, flutter-packages

I'm working on a project and I intend to use the Flutter framework but is it possible to create a live video broadcast like that of Instagram or Facebook live?